# Не перемещается background в css

Tags: html, css, mvc

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Main</title>
    <link href="~/CSS/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/CSS/Prolist.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="newbgr2">
        
    </div>

    <div class="bgr"> 
        
        
        
        <a class="button7" href="@Url.Action("Registration")">Авторизація</a>

        <a class="button7" href="@Url.Action("Main", "Main")">Main Page</a>

        <a class="button7" href="@Url.Action("Main", "Main")">Main Page</a>

        <a class="button7" href="@Url.Action("Main", "Main")">Main Page</a>

        <a class="button7" href="@Url.Action("Main", "Main")">Main Page</a>

        <a class="button7" href="@Url.Action("Main", "Main")">Main Page</a>


       
    </div>
   
   
    <div class="newbgr">

        <a class="opacity">
           
            <p>
                ПП"НВФ"ЄвроТел-Україна"<br>
                 тел.роб.(0536)70-15-50<br>
                 тел.роб.(0536)70-15-40<br>
                 факс    (0536)74-01-11<br>
                 моб.    (050)30-80-539<br>
                         (067)53-18-539<br>
            </p>
           
            
           
           
           
        </a>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема заключается в том что красный прямоугольник (приведены картинки) должен стать на пустое место, margin-bottom не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![

```css
/*Код backgrounds*/

.bgr{
  
    margin-left:1135px;
    background: blue;
    
    width:15%;
    height:83vh;
    
    background-size:cover;
}
.newbgr2{
    
    background: red;
    width:84%;
    height:83vh;
    background-size:cover;
   }
.newbgr{
   background: rgb(33,147,90);
    width:100%;
    height:17vh;
    background-size:cover;

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

}
```

[image: ][2]]][3]

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX3is.png]

Comment: Приложите HTML в виде кода.

Comment: добавил код в правку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это то, чего нужно было добиться?

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.bgr{
    background: blue;
    width:16%;
    height:83vh;
    background-size:cover;
}
.newbgr2{
    background: red;
    width:84%;
    height:83vh;
    background-size:cover;
   }
.newbgr{
   background: rgb(33,147,90);
   width:100%;
   height:17vh;
   background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="newbgr2"></div>
  <div class="bgr"><a href="@Url.Action(" class="button7">Авторизація</a><a href="@Url.Action(" class="button7">Main Page</a><a href="@Url.Action(" class="button7">Main Page</a><a href="@Url.Action(" class="button7">Main Page</a><a href="@Url.Action(" class="button7">Main Page</a><a href="@Url.Action(" class="button7">Main Page</a></div>
  <div class="newbgr"><a class="opacity">
      <p>ПП"НВФ"ЄвроТел-Україна"<br/>                 тел.роб.(0536)70-15-50<br/>                 тел.роб.(0536)70-15-40<br/>                 факс    (0536)74-01-11<br/>                 моб.    (050)30-80-539<br/>                         (067)53-18-539<br/></p></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Обратите внимание на то что HTML тоже поменялся. Появилась дополнительная обертка.

Comment: html тоже поменял

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю суть проблемы :-(

Comment: я понял для чего обертка, но вывод остался прежним, (по идее красный контейнер должен сместится вниз и стать на пустое место)

Comment: А какой у вас браузер?

Comment: goooooooooooogle chrome

Comment: А вы в обертку засунули то что было внутри body и добавили стиль для обертки? Вот в этом примере работает? https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/bWMqex

Comment: засунул, а что значит стиль для обертки?

Comment: .wrapper {...} то что в коде ответа к вопросу.

Comment: да,+ добавил margin-bottom:1000px; красному фону вывод привел в вопросе

Comment: А зачем margin-bottom: 1000px. Что сейчас не так в полсденем скриншоте?

Comment: теперь зеленый фон сместился вниз

Comment: уберите margin-bottom: 1000px

Comment: блин)не обновил браузер наверное и не заметил что все норм ,Спасибо!)